# ListView Edit item Position

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a Listview in my aspx page with Insert template and Edit template. and a Add New LinkButton.

When a user clicks on Add New LinkButton I am able to specify Insertitem Position so that the Insert TEmplate appears at the bottom of the listview. But how to I make the edititem template to appear at the bottom like the Inserttemplate

Answer (score 0):

Its not available for the EditItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to actually save the original position, move the item in the data source itself (probably `IList` compatible), rebind the view, trigger editing on the new position, then swap the data item back to the original position.

I wouldn't recommend it.  It's nonintuitive behaviour for users anyway; when I decide to edit something I should either be able to edit in place or edit on an entirely separate form.  It's very rarely good UI design to shuffle items around while users are working on them, especially if you have any sort of scrolling/paging going on.